transform:translate(-50%,-50%) doesn't work well with transform:scale()
I am centering my element with class "play__circle" using position: absolute; (parent container is set to position:relative;) but when I use transform:scale() then the element doesn't stay in the center anymore.
Initially the "play__circle" his hidden, but on hover its opacity is set to 1 and scale(0.7).


.container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(208, 174, 191, 0.8);
  position: relative;
  padding:5px;
}

.play__circle{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  opacity:0;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, transform    300ms ease-in-out;
}

.container:hover .play__circle{
  opacity: 1;
  transform:scale(0.7)
}

.content__one{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(205, 184, 86, 0.8);
}

.content__two{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(232, 125, 52, 0.8);
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="play__circle">

  </div>
  <div class="content__one">

  </div>
  <div class="content__two">

  </div>
</div>




.container:hover .play__circle should include both properties, so transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.7);

TL;DR. transform properties need to be fully specified when animating
The main concern in your case is that you have transform: translate(-50%, -50%); in your base styling, and only animating it by transform: scale(0.7); on hover. When animating a CSS property with multiple values, you often need to include all custom set values.
That is, when you hover a mouse, CSS will transition only between scale(1) and scale(0.7) values and simply ignore the translate(-50%, -50%) since it's not specified.
UPDATED:
As @temani mentioned in the comment, transform-origin shouldn't have to be adjusted, given the scale is set after translate.
ORIGINAL ANSWER (IGNORE):
Also, you'd need to specify the transform-origin to top left corner, since you repositioned it by transform and it's no longer animating from the visual center. See the snippet below.


.container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(208, 174, 191, 0.8);
  position: relative;
  padding:5px;
}

.play__circle{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  opacity:0;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out, transform 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.container:hover .play__circle{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.7); /* This line is edited */
}

.content__one{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(205, 184, 86, 0.8);
}

.content__two{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(232, 125, 52, 0.8);
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="play__circle">

  </div>
  <div class="content__one">

  </div>
  <div class="content__two">

  </div>
</div>




don't do this. Define scale after translate so you don't have to mess with the transform-origin

@TemaniAfif Thanks for the feedback. You're absolutely right, and I just edited the snippet to remove the unnecessary transform-origin adjustment and corrected the write-up as well.
